# How to show Emoji using TMP_InputField or TMP_Text in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to input emoji supported using TextMeshPro in Unity.
But it's not working correctly.
I inputted "\U0001F600" but didn't show <> emoticon.
Anybody knows about this or has some experience to use Emoticon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to input raw Unicode in text, for instance

```
xxx.text = "\U0001F600";
```

But it was wrong and it was inputted "\U0001F600".
If you use this emoticon, please input a string like this.

```
xxx.text = <sprite=0>
```